# Printing text file with Java

Tags: java, text, printing

I am trying to print a text file using the given code. Everything goes fine: the job goes in the printing queue of the printer. However after some time, it disappears and nothing is printed. Also, there isn't an exception or error in the code. Everything goes fine, except it is not printing. I am not using a print API.

```
public class PipedPrint implements Runnable {
    PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
    byte[] abPrinterBytes = null;

    private void mainProcess() throws IOException, PrintException, InterruptedException {
        abPrinterBytes = getBytesFromFile();
        pis.connect(pos);
        Thread randWriter = new Thread(this);
        randWriter.start();
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
        PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);
        if (defaultService != null) {
            DocPrintJob job = defaultService.createPrintJob();
            DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(pis, flavor, das);
            System.out.println("Main::Fired Print");
            job.print(doc, pras);
            System.out.println("Main::Done Print");
        }
        randWriter.join();
        System.out.println("Main::Join Over");
    }

    private byte[] getBytesFromFile() throws IOException {
        File fFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Wijdan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\demo_print\\src\\demo_print\\pass.txt"); //File to print
        byte[] abFileBytes = new byte[(int) fFile.length()];
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fFile));
        for (int i = 0; i < abFileBytes.length; i += in .read(abFileBytes, i, (abFileBytes.length - i)));
        return abFileBytes;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("RandWriter started Writing");
            for (int i = 0; i < abPrinterBytes.length; i += 400) {
                pos.write(abPrinterBytes, i, ((i + 400) < abPrinterBytes.length) ? 400 : (abPrinterBytes.length - i));
                System.out.println("Thread:: Wrote bytes. Sleeping....");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            pos.close();
            System.out.println("Thread::Closed pos. Exitting Thread...");
        } catch (Exception ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipedPrint t1 = new PipedPrint();
        try {
            t1.mainProcess();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug ?

Comment: what specificaly i should debug?

Comment: i forgot to mention ms one note also open after i hit the print button in print dialog

Comment: Yes, I just saw that......by the way, tell me in simple words (very brief), what is the issue

Comment: file isnt printing.

Comment: is there anything that my printer needs to print from third party applications?

Comment: Boss, I don't understand what is the issue at your system, but trust me, just now only I 've run your code only and collected the paper from our printing machine.....you see if the default printer is set in your system and if the default printer is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Check if

1. **All the imports are :**

   `import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PipedInputStream;
   import java.io.PipedOutputStream;`

   `import javax.print.Doc;
   import javax.print.DocFlavor;
   import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
   import javax.print.PrintException;
   import javax.print.PrintService;
   import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
   import javax.print.ServiceUI;
   import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
   import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
   import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
   import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
   import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;`
2. **Ensure the file path is valid**
3. **Your current printer is set as default printer at your system and if it is working**

Comment: everything seems to be fine it goes in the printing queue and then dsappers from there

Comment: You mean to say the file is getting disappearing from the printing queue right ?

Comment: after setting the printer as default printer there is no output on console and the problem persists.

Comment: which printer you are using, tell me in detail of the printer name and version and bit version

Comment: no library is needed , everything is fine.....just tell me in detail of the printer name and version and bit version

Comment: HP LaserJet Professional P1102 64 bit win 8

Comment: can you just give a sample text file to print using the same HP LaserJet printer ? Just right click and click print

Comment: Printer is fine and printing files from other than this application i have tried and its printing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code it was working fine in my case. My printer name is HP LaserJet 4250.

I think their may be issue of file size you are giving for printing. Please try sending file in chunks instead of sending all at a time.

However even when I click "Cancel" in the UI screen part for cancelling the print, it still gives the printout.